# In vue.js v-validate not working with multiselect

Tags: vue.js

' v-validate' in vue.js not working with `<multiselect>` when i submit form `v-on:submit.prevent='fun()'`

```
<div class="select-inp">
    <multiselect v-model="selectedShifts"
                 track-by="shift_name"
                 label="shift_name"
                 placeholder="Working shift" 
                 :options="shifts" 
                 :searchable="true"
                 v-validate="'required'">
     </multiselect>
</div>
```

Comment: So you're using VeeValidate v2 for validating your multiselect? And is it this multiselect package you're using? https://vue-multiselect.js.org/

Comment: I shared your answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68221284/problems-using-vee-validates-field-and-vue-multiselect/72036609#72036609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to make `validation` custom using by `if(){}else{}` because , 
`v-on:submit.prevent='fun()` not working correctly and make my button type submit in form ,
using `required` only , and now it work correctly